# How to access the userdata data file using cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am trying to access my Userdata.txt as a file rather than to code the whole powershell script again in the  "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": section. Is it possible to access the Userdata file stored in the s3 to be accessed with a link which is publicly acceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes, you can download a file and execute it as part of your instance's bootstrap.

Longer answer is you still need to have the bootstrap code - the code to download your main file from s3 - executed somehow, and this must be in User data. On a Linux box:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
wget https://mybucket.s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/myscript.sh
chmod +x myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
```

on Windows:

```bash
<powershell>
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://mybucket.s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/myscript.ps1" -OutFile ".\myscript.ps1"
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass # see comments
.\myscript.ps1
</powershell>
```

Note the implications of setting execution [policy to bypass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6). Additionally, above assumes your scripts are in a public bucket but they can be amended to make an authenticated s3 download.